# How can I add for each grouped object new key value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi all I have following array

```
    const arr = [
      {
       ImageFileSet: [{ id: 1 }],
       LineItemFile: "new name",
       LineItemRef: "PDF",
       id: 44  
      },

       {
       ImageFileSet: [{ id: 7 }, { id: 8 }, { id: 9 }],
       LineItemFile: null,
       LineItemRef: "Image"
       id: 124
      },

    ];
```

I am trying to group array of objects in new array with following code

```
    const allFiles = arr .flatMap(({ ImageFileSet }) => [ImageFileSet]);
```

Output is

```
    [ { id: 1 }, { id: 7 }, { id: 8 }, { id: 9 } ]
```

Now how can I also add `LineItemFile` for each object ?

I want final result something like

```
    [ { id: 1,  LineItemFile: "new name", }, { id: 7,LineItemFile: null, }, { id: 8 , 
       LineItemFile: null,}, { id: 9 , LineItemFile: null,} ]
```

Please help me resolve this.

I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366479/group-object-keys-with-accumalated-value-in-new-array-in-javascript) article but it not helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do something like this

```js
const arr = [{
    ImageFileSet: [{
      id: 1
    }],
    LineItemFile: "new name",
    LineItemRef: "PDF",
    id: 44
  },
  {
    ImageFileSet: [{
      id: 7
    }, {
      id: 8
    }, {
      id: 9
    }],
    LineItemFile: null,
    LineItemRef: "Image",
    id: 124
  },
];

const result = arr.flatMap(({ImageFileSet,LineItemFile}) =>
  ImageFileSet.map(d => ({ ...d, LineItemFile}))
)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
    const allFiles = arr.flatMap((lineItem) => {
      return lineItem.ImageFileSet.map((imageFileSet) => (
          {...imageFileSet, LineItemFile: lineItem.LineItemFile}
        }))
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
const allFiles = arr.flatMap((obj) =>
    obj.ImageFileSet.flat().map((id) => ({
    ...id,
    LineItemFile: obj.LineItemFile
    }))
);
```

Output :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "LineItemFile": "new name"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "LineItemFile": null
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "LineItemFile": null
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "LineItemFile": null
    }
]
```